# Keyboard replacement done but same keys won't work anyways

Tags: laptop, keyboard, replacement

Laptop keyboard replacement

Guys so i tried to change my laptop keyboard it was kinda hard but i made it. Here's the link of the video i used: https://youtu.be/9PIgQCyYZwA

Now my problem is that the same keys that didn't work on the old keyboard are not working on the new keyboard neither. Have any idea? My laptop is great has i5, ssd and 16 gb ram.
I don't want to buy a new one since it's a pretty good computer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I suggest a repair-shop.

Comment: Try an external keyboard. If that doesn't work, then the issue is software/drivers, e.g., an external program intercepting the key press. If it does work, it could be the *keyboard controller* that's broken, or a board trace, which require professional repair -- just keep using the external keyboard, if you want.

Comment: Thanks folks. I will take it to a repair-shop